# Insert dynamically a React component in a div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'd like to insert dynamically several React component in a div HTML 
element. Every time that I click on button, I would like to add a new `PeriodButtonContainer` inside div with `id="container"`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class Period extends React.Component {
  addPeriodHandler = () => {
    /****?????******/
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="container">
          <PeriodButtonContainer />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="addPeriod" onClick={this.addPeriodHandler}>
            Add a period
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should increment a counter in your state, create an array of the length of the counter and map it to your element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could keep a counter that you increment on each button click, and create that many `PeriodButtonContainer` components in your render method with e.g. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

**Example**

```
class Period extends React.Component {
  state = { periods: 1 };

  addPeriodHandler = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { periods: previousState.periods + 1 };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="container">
          {Array.from({ length: this.state.periods }, (_, index) => (
            <PeriodButtonContainer key={index} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="addPeriod" onClick={this.addPeriodHandler}>
            Add a period
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```